# Codeforces - 260B - Runtime Error

Tags: c++, runtime-error

I am constantly getting Runtime error for test-12 of this problem:
http://codeforces.com/problemset/problem/260/B
My submissions are as follows:
http://codeforces.com/contest/260/submission/17270090
http://codeforces.com/contest/260/submission/17269920

Can someone please point out some test case where my code would fail?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is possible to be caused by the `stoi` function, which throws an exception if its input is not a number.